# Gelfand-Tsetlin Problem.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I've been tasked with finding an orthonormal basis for the $gl(3)$-module $V(\varepsilon_1 - \varepsilon_3)$, then giving the matrix of generators $a_{2}^{1}, a_{1}^{2}, a_{1}^{1}$ and $a_{2}^{2}$ in the corresponding representation, and give the branching rule for $gl(2) \subset gl(3)$ in this case.

So, I started with the branching rule, noting that $V(\varepsilon_1 - \varepsilon_3) = (1,0,-1)$, and obtained the following G-T patterns (with the weights underneath);
[image]

My only concern with this was that I had two $(0,0,0)$ weights. Nevertheless, I plowed ahead, and using the lowering generators $a_{1}^{2}$ and $a_{2}^{3}$ on the highest weight vector acquired from before, $(1,0,-1)$, I got the following branching pattern;[image]

Now, my problem here is two-fold; I'm not sure to which G-T pattern the $(0,0,0)$ belongs to, and, this seems to imply an orthonormal basis $(1,0,-1) = (1,-1) \oplus (1,0) \oplus (0,-1)$. Does this make sense?? I'm really not sure.

Any verification/help/tips on what I've done so far would be absolutely fantastic. :)